# Is there a quicker way to "Right click + Copy Image" on any browser on Mac?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, web-browser, contextual-menu

I use Orion mainly since it adds a bit more screen area without going into fullscreen using their compact bar. Irrespective, a repetitive task I need during making notes is right clicking images and pasting them into another App (ex. Notion, Goodnotes) to make a note I can review later.

Having to right click + move cursor to find the option of 'Copy Image' takes times and is frustrating (especially with the small options on Mac [but I do not want to make that larger]).

If not that, is there a way the Right Click menu options can be reordered. Currently "Search with Google", "Look up [word]" are the top options. This would surely be the second preferred option.

Is there a quicker way to automate Right Click + Copy image when I'm hovering over an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drag and drop is the quickest. You can drop to the end of any existing line, or in an empty line…

[image]
<sub>The circle indicates click or hold.</sub>

You either need the screen space to be able to see both at once, or you can  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   to bring the text app to the front without letting go of the dragged image.

Comment: I suppose so this is the best way, thanks for the help king stranger! The Cmd + Tab was something that I did not think of. Appreciate the help!